# cydia-substrate tweak development - giving errors on make

Tags: mobile, tweak, cydia-substrate

I am new to making mobile substrate tweaks and I wanted to hook this function but having a bit of trouble.

```
%hook classname

- (void)function:(BOOL) {

%orig;
return TRUE;

}

%end
```

but when i try to MAKE this it gives me an error. void function should not return a value.

I just want to change the BOOL to always return true.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your aim is vague a bit. The error is because your function header is

```
- (void)function:(BOOL) foo {
%orig;
return YES;
}
```

This means function `function` has a boolean argument and **RETURNS NOTHING**. So you can't write `return YES` in your function. This line causes the error.

If your goal is to return the value of the original function with `YES` argument no matter what `foo` is, you have to rewrite your function like below:

```
- (void)function:(BOOL) foo {
%orig(YES);
}
```